# Query HTTP Calls Made to My Salesforce Org

Tags: apex, soql, api

I would like to know how to obtain the HTTP calls made to a Salesforce org. The org has a few connected third party applications and I would like to identify which applications are making certain callouts and I need it to be done programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to know API calls that are being made into  your Salesforce Org? I.e. calling the `query` API call from a 3rd party application external from Salesforce?

Comment: Yes I just need a way to obtain,query the Incoming http requests

Comment: You should be able retrieve this information by parsing the `EventLogFile` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm

Comment: the thing is that I need to obtain those records right after the call has been made to salesforce "An event log file is generated when an event occurs in your organization and is available to view and download after 24 hours"    Thanks

Comment: You may also want to look into Enhanced transaction security https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (near) real-time event monitoring, you'll need to license Salesforce Shield or Event Monitoring add-ons. The events (known as `ApiEventStream`) are stored in Big Objects.

It is near real-time because platform events are used to publish the data to the Big Object.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.real_time_event_monitoring_overview.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  As a service to the Community, would you be so kind as to mark as Answered if in fact, the answer addressed your question.